# Opera browser shows 403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: forms-authentication, 403

Opera browser gives 403 FORBIDDEN when trying to access my SharePoint site. The site uses FBA authentication and is an internet facing site. In IIS logs I can see that Opera has requested the favicon. 
The site works fine with other major browsers (I7, I8, I9, FF, Chrome, Safari). The same problem occurs with http and https.

Comment: Same question's at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884913/sharepoint-2010-fba-site-and-opera Bottom line seems to be that SharePoint's specifically looking for the string "Mozilla" in user-agent strings to tell browsers from WebDAV clients and since Opera doesn't have that string, it's a problem. I haven't found a fix to this yet, but I can't believe a system as robust as SharePoint should be doesn't have a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find a [similar issue reported in msdn](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/3bf9b899-99a7-418d-9545-80dd531942bc/) with FBA authentication and Opera browser.

As the post suggests,

Opera browser is not on the supported browser list for SharePoint. Chrome isn't on the list either, although that one normally works.  Opera has always had issues with SharePoint and it isn't fixed in 2010. Here's the list of approved browsers.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx